# How to generate random locations with a pixel value of 1–12?

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, random

The attached Matlab script creates random numbers in a 300-by-400 array. The "white" locations in the image below have a value of 255. All other values are 0.  How can I alter this code so that the random locations are integers from 1 to 12 rather than all equal to 255?

```
% Generate a totally black image to start with.
m = zeros(300, 400, 'uint8');

% Generate 1000 random locations.
numRandom = 1000;
linearIndices = randi(numel(m), 1, numRandom);

% Set those locations to be "white".
m(linearIndices) = 255;

% Display it.  Random locations will appear white.
image(m);
colormap(gray);
```

[image]

Comment: In the current code the random locations are not 255 as you say. They are spread all along and across the image. What do you want to change?

Comment: The _locations_ are spread across the image. The _values_ at those locations are 255. See my answer; is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace the *value* 255 by random values between 1 and 12, change line

```
m(linearIndices) = 255;
```

to

```
m(linearIndices) = randi(12, [numel(linearIndices) 1]);
```